# How to trigger a FCM from cloud function for a specific field update in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I recently wrote a cloud function that sends a notification to a specific user when there is a specific update in a document and it works fine. But as you can see in my code inside each case I added the code to trigger a notification whenever the case satisfies but the user receives notification even all the switch cases fail. I'm really confused about this issue.

For a better explanation:
**ServiceStatus** are of five types

1. Type - 1
2. Type - 2
3. Type - 3
4. Type - 4
5. Type - 5

I want the notification to be sent to the user only when the type - 1, 3, 5 are updated in the ServiceStatus else the function trigger should be ignored. For this, I wrote a switch case but that is not working as I expected it triggers a notification for all five types even though two cases won't satisfy.

my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.OrderUpdates = functions.firestore.document('orders/{ServiceID}').onWrite(async (event) =>{

    const service_id = event.after.get('ServiceID');
    const title = event.after.get('ServiceStatus');
    let body;
    const fcmToken = event.after.get('FCMToken');
    const technician_name = event.after.get('TechnicianName');

    switch(title){
        case "Service Raised":
            body = "Thanks for raising a service request with us. Please wait for sometime our customer care executive will respond to your request";
            var message = {
                token: fcmToken,
                notification: {
                    title: title,
                    body: body,
                },
                "android": {
                    "notification": {
                      "channel_id": "order_updates"
                    }
                  },
                data: {
                    "Service ID": service_id,
                },
            }
        
            let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
            console.log(response);
            break;
        case "Technician Assigned":
            body = "Our Technician " + technician_name + " has been assigned to your service request. You can contact him now to proceed further";
            var message = {
                token: fcmToken,
                notification: {
                    title: title,
                    body: body,
                },
                "android": {
                    "notification": {
                      "channel_id": "order_updates"
                    }
                  },
                data: {
                    "Service ID": service_id,
                },
            }
        
            let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
            console.log(response);
            break;
        case "Service Completed":
            body = "Your Service request has been successfully completed. Please rate and review our service and help us to serve better. \n Thanks for doing business with us..!!";
            var message = {
                token: fcmToken,
                notification: {
                    title: title,
                    body: body,
                },
                "android": {
                    "notification": {
                      "channel_id": "order_updates"
                    }
                  },
                data: {
                    "Service ID": service_id,
                },
            }
        
            let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
            console.log(response);
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: We can't see what the inputs are to this function, so we don't really have a way to debugging this for you with what you have now.  You're going to have to edit the question to show the full steps you take to trigger this function, including what you do to the document to cause this code to run.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce and observe the behavior.

Comment: As you can see from the code when a new document is created, updated in a particular collection then this function will be triggered. So, to limit that I wrote the switch statement to send the notification only when the case satisfies but the notification is getting triggered even the case doesn't satisfy and this is the error I'm struggling to solve. In a gunshot how can i trigger a function only when a specific field is updated

Comment: You can't specify only a single field. The function will trigger when anything changes in any matching document. You have to check the contents to see what changed.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499286/how-to-make-an-action-triggered-only-if-a-field-is-changed-using-onupdate-trigge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to send a message when the status field is actively changed, you'll want to compare the value of that field as it existed before this write operation and as it'll exist after the write.

To do this, get the field value from the `before` and `after` snapshots:

```
const beforeTitle = event.before ? event.before.get('ServiceStatus') : "";
const afterTitle = event.after ? event.after.get('ServiceStatus') : "";
```

You'll note that I also check if `event.before` and `event.after` exist, as your Cloud Function will also be triggered upon document creation (at which point `event.before` will be undefined) and document deletion (at which point `event.after` will be undefined).

Now with those two values you can check whether the `ServiceStatus` field was just given a value that should trigger a message to be sent with a series of `if` statements, like

```
if (afterStatus == "Service Raised" && beforeStatus != "Service Raised") {
  ... send relevant message
}
```