# Can we listen specific key value changes in firestore angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

```
getUserEventSummaryE(userId) {

return docData(doc(this.firestore, `/user/${userId}/event_summary/current/`), {idField : 'playing_summary'}).
  pipe(distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => _.isEqual(prev, curr)));

}
```

**getUserEventSummaryE** should only return document when **playing_summary** changes but current it returning document data when other than `playing_summary` key value changes.

Example Document data

```
{
id: 1,
playing_summary: 'playing',
userbalance: 222,
dob: '2021-05-02'
}
```

When I change Other than `playing_summary` then currently changes triggering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't listen to any key-values in the documents, but you can do that on document. It's only triggered when a document is updated.

```
exports.dbEventsOnUpdate = functions.firestore
.document('events/{eventId}').onUpdate(async (change,context) => {
   
            const eventID = context.params.eventId;
            const newValue = change.after.data();
            const previousValue = change.before.data();
            const titleIsUpdated = newValue.title !== previousValue.title;
    })
```

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499286/how-to-make-an-action-triggered-only-if-a-field-is-changed-using-onupdate-trigge) link for more details.

Comment: I can't do this into firebase function as I have to fire GOOGLE ANALYTICS 4 Tags which not supporting there

Comment: So, if you want to make changes in the above `getUserEventSummaryE `, you can't do it on key-value pair.